# Where should I use "over the past decade" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, time, placement

It seems to me that it is better to use **'over the past decade'** at the start of this sentence rather than the end, although I am not too sure why!

> - *"There is an ever increasing number of people deciding to pursue their post graduate education in Taiwan **over the past decade**."*

> - *"**Over the past decade,** there is an increasing number of people deciding to pursue their post graduate education in Taiwan."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is an ever increasing number of people deciding to pursue their post graduate education in Taiwan over the past decade.

Here, there can be an ambiguity whether this sentence refers to the fact that the number of people increases ***over the past decade*** or to the fact that people decided (***over the past decade***) to pursue their post graduate education in Taiwan.

> Over the past decade, there is an increasing number of people deciding to pursue their post graduate education in Taiwan.

Here, there is no doubt that ***over the past decade*** indicates the time when the number of such people increased.

Comment: Yes, moving this bit forward clears things up...  But I feel there should be a comma after the clause, what do you think?

Comment: I totally agree. I will insert it.